# How to remove a row from mysql data base using JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

How can I remove a row from database using Mysql database using `JTable`. What I'm trying to do is when user select the row and click delete button I want to delete that row from data base.

```
private void deleteItemBtn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
    try{
        if(jTable2.getSelectedRowCount()== 1){
            int SelectedRowIndex = jTable2.getSelectedRow();
            int row = jTable2.getSelectedRow();
            String eve = model.getValueAt(row, 4).toString();
            expenseDAO.deleteRow(eve);
            model.removeRow(SelectedRowIndex);

        }else{
           if(jTable2.getRowCount()==0){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Table is Empty");
           }else{
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please slelect s ingle row for Delete");
           }
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

This is my deleteRow method :

```
public void deleteRow(String value){
    String query = "DELETE FROM expense WHERE ex_id ="+value;
    Statement st;
    try {
        st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ExpenseDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This code not working.

Comment: What is 'not working'? Please give some detailed description of the actual and the expected behaviour.

Comment: @AZWN it's delete row from the jTable but  not deleting the row from the database. I want to delete the row once user select and click the delete button

Comment: 1) I'm not an SQL expert but I believe you are missing `'...'` around the String identifying the row you want to remove.  Use a `PreparedStatement` for the SQL. It is easier to provide parameters so you don't need to worry about using delimiters in the SQL statement. You can search the forum for examples using a `PreparedStatement` 2) This is not a Swing issue. First get your SQL working using the PreparedStatement and a hardcoded value for the parameter. Once that works then you use the getValueAt(...) method to dynamically get the value for the row to be deleted.